# Llamada Ajax con un click

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax

Estoy muy perdida con este proyecto y necesito una guía.

Estoy llenando una Lista con personajes cuya información viene de una Api, estos son 10, dentro de esta información está el link de las películas en las que aparecen, mi idea es darle clic a cada uno de estos personajes y me aparezca la información (Texto, descripción e imagen ) de la película en la que aparece.

Aquí está mi código con dos llamadas Ajax, así que cuando haga clic en un personaje me muestre información de la película, pero me dice este error

```
caught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at peliculas (four.js:43)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM22962 index_3.html:1)
```

siendo mi error en

```
films=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

Dejo mi codigo completo

```
    function personajes(url, callback) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                try {
                    var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                } catch(err) {

                    return;
                }
                callback(data);
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    personajes("https://swapi.co/api/people/", function(data) {


        var persons=data.results;
        var html ;

        var container = document.querySelector(".text ul");

           for(var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++){

              var item = container.innerHTML += "<li><a class='ajax_item' onClick= 'peliculas()' href='#' > "+ persons[i].name + "</a></li>";

           // var item = document.querySelectorAll(".ajax_item").setAttribute('films', JSON.stringify(el.films));
             //item.setAttribute('films', JSON.stringify(data.films));

           }

    })

    function peliculas()
    {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        films=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

        var list=document.querySelector('#results');
        list.innerHTML= "";

        films.forEach(function(url)
        {
            //console.log(43, url);
            var xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange= function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState ===4)
            {
                if (xmlhttp.status === 200){

                    film= JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    //console.log(film.title);

                    li=document.createElement("li");
                    li.innerHTML=film.title;
                    //li.innerHTML=film.opening_crawl;
                    list.appendChild(li);

                }

            }
        }

            xmlhttp.open('GET', url);
            xmlhttp.send();
        })
    }
```

Así es mi html

```
    </ul>

</div>

<div class="results">
<ul>
</ul>
</div>
```

Estoy muy perdida y no Se como hacerlo.

Comment: No me termina de quedar clara la parte de "_Cómo hago para mostrar la información de una película en la que aparecen, por que hasta ahora me sale la información como si fuera una lista._" ¿Cómo quieres que salga la información?

Comment: Estás segura que lo que te está llegando en un JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que la función peliculas no funciona igual que la función personajes, que es la que está bien implementada. De hecho, podrías renombrar esa función y reutilizarla para las películas:

```js
 function personajes(url, callback) { //se podría renombrar a obtenerDatos
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                try {
                    var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                } catch(err) {

                    return;
                }
                callback(data);
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    personajes("https://swapi.co/api/people/", function gestionoPersonajes(data) {
      console.log(data.results[0])
    });

    personajes("https://swapi.co/api/films/", function gestionoPeliculas(data) {
      console.log(data.results[0])
    });
```

Comment: Pero no se ejecuta con un click es decir necesito que cuando se de click la funcion de peliculas me muestre una pelicula